# How to explain "Cool" to a Briton

Tags: single-word-requests, british-english, slang

I was recently having a conversation with a friend from England. During the conversation I described someone as being *cool*, but he seemed confused by the term and asked me what I meant.

I couldn't really explain to him that well what it would equate to in UK English. Does anyone know of a good way to explain "cool" to someone who isn't familiar with the term?

Comment: I said I was aware they're considered westerners, poor wording on my part I guess.

Comment: It's hard to imagine a native English speaker who isn't familiar with this use of _cool_. It's been common for at least 50 years.

Comment: Agreed, it sort of caught me off-guard, hence why I wasn't able to explain what it meant. It's just something that's common knowledge to most native English speakers.

Comment: I'm not sure whether it originated in America or England, but I'm pretty sure it crossed the pond long ago -- I'm sure I heard British Beatles fans use it in clips from the 60's.

Comment: I admit that I'd probably have a hard time describing it without using other colloquialisms that he might not know, like _hip_ or _with it_.

Comment: It is subjective.  It is like saying something is beautiful, which led to the study of [aesthetics.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aesthetics)

Comment: There's no easy way to define what *cool* means because it's such a vague term in the first place. My "young adult" children might say I'm "cool" because they like the way I interact with their friends, because they think I'm a sharp dresser, or simply because I'm usually fairly relaxed. Well, actually they probably *wouldn't*, because they *don't* usually think I'm particularly cool. But it's noticeable that poor communicators use vague terms like this a lot, because it *saves them having to think of exactly what they really mean* (which they may not have the vocabulary to express anyway).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think perhaps the difference between America and Britain in this regard is that the former consider it 'cool' to say 'cool'.

Comment: Maybe he wants to know if you mean "one who partakes..."  i.e. - [this context](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KovhRkeHG4c)

Comment: Obviously the best way to "explain" it is simply to play a recording of Miles Davis from the 1950s.

Comment: @WS2: I think it's more a matter of which side of 50 you are, rather than which side of the Atlantic. Not that I think using "cool" is inherently "uncool" - I just get irritated when people use it *constantly*. It's like people who swear every other word, or keep parroting the latest catchphrases. An utterance that seems to "fit" almost everywhere must almost by definition have an extremely vague meaning. But IMHO if you can't explain *exactly* what you mean by any given term ***using other words***, you've no business using that term in the first place 'cos you don't know what you're saying.

Comment: @FumbleFingers OED meaning 8a, covers the point.  *Attractively shrewd or clever; sophisticated, stylish, classy; fashionable, up to date; sexually attractive.* It has entries dating from 1884, but the word was probably coined (they say) around 1918.

Comment: @WS2: Not to mention OED defn 2d *assured and unabashed where diffidence and hesitation would be expected* - a sense first recorded 1723. Much as I like Miles Davis, I do despair of people who assume the current usage must be [coeval](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/coeval) with [*Birth of the Cool*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birth_of_the_Cool).

Comment: Perhaps it's more that the person didn't understand why you thought someone was cool, rather than not understanding what 'cool' meant? Perhaps they believed the 'someone' in question to be decidedly 'uncool' and wondered what on earth you were talking about? What had you seen that they hadn't?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

People in England know lots of meanings for the word cool. As a personality trait, it can mean **aloof**, **trendy**, **laid-back**, **sound**, or **accomplished**, and probably many more things too, even before you start thinking of its meaning more widely. Each of these meanings can be quite distinct from the others.

If someone from the UK was asking you what you meant, they were either seeking clarification or being contrary.

Maybe you could choose a meaning from the above words or, -- to be facetious for a moment, -- find someone more co-operative to talk with?

Examples of these different usages:

- Doris has always been warm and giving, but Eva is often a little cool. [aloof]
- Is this where the cool kids go? [trendy]
- No, you're fine. He is cool with high-test peroxide. [unanxious]
- Don't worry about him deceiving you, he's cool. [sound]
- He is one cool accordion player. [accomplished]

Comment: I agree with everything here (good "spread" of possible meanings in contemporary usage contexts). But it might be worth explicitly making the point which seems to be at least strongly *implied* by those examples. Neither OP, you, nor anyone else could possibly give an *exact synonym* or single definition for "cool" as used today, because it has a *range* of meanings. I hate to allude to my age, but I can remember when *some* (but not all) of those meanings could be conveyed by *fab, swinging, far-out*, etc.

Answer (score 3):

'Cool' is one of those words whose signification has shifted (in my (English) experience) more often than most. In the 1950s it meant Miles Davis and sharp suits. In the 60s this carried on into the mod image, but also came to be applied to anything from Che Guevara to patchouli oil. More lately, smartphones, tablets are all described as 'cool'.

What  does 'cool' mean? Perhaps **unflappability in the face of overwhelming complexity.**

Comment: So close to being a *cool answer*, so close. By Jove, it is!

Answer (score 1):

It completely depends upon the inflection you give the word "cool" and the facial expressions that accompany it as well. 
An example of such was done with the word "dude" in 'Dude Where's My Car'. 
Cool can mean many different things if you want it to.